# What is "meta" in the context of Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2, terminology

Due to the recent update to Guild Wars 2, which has changed the trait system, I've heard lots of people asking "What's the new meta?" and "Meta hasn't been outed yet"

In this context, what does "meta" mean? I assume they are talking about specific builds, or trait and skill combinations, so why is it called 'meta'?

Comment: As an example to this; when I play chess against my friend, I know that he is liable to use specific tactics. Therefore, I make moves that are not the most optimal chess move (objectively), but _because I know how my friend plays the game_. That is meta gameplay. **You play the opponent, not just the game.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Meta** is a term commonly used in MMO's to describe the current best builds and strategies, short for *metagame*.

It comes from the greek *meta*, which indicates an abstraction from a concept ; so this is used to designate everything related to the game, not explicitely told by the game.

There is a nice [Wikpedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metagaming) about it.

And yeah, I think GW2 is the game where I have heard this word the most. When meta becomes the most important thing, that's when I usually grow tired of the game and quit.

Comment: *Metagame* can also stand for "achievements", which I love :)

Comment: `damage formulae` is not a good example - it IS part of the game itself. Metagame, in this context especially, usually refers to player consensus of   strategies, what is worth doing and what is not, effective talent tree choices etc.

Comment: Maybe you're right. However, damage formulae are not usually told to users, so I assumed it was safe to call them meta.